# How to check if a particular element in an array has a char

Tags: java

How can I read through the items in an array, and check if they contain a string. Something like the indexOf method?

```
String[] myArray = {"Jo [M]", "Sally [F]"};
Male = "[M]"
for(i = 0; myArray.length(); i = i + 1){
if(myArray[i].indexOf(Male){
System.out.println("Contains M")

//Do stuff

}
```

Comment: `myArray[i].contains(Male)`.. you should really show more of a research effort..

Comment: What happens when you try to compile and run this code?

Comment: Honest to god I searched through at least 15 stack overflows, none of which I could draw that from. Thanks

Comment: @JakeHenderson try looking at the Javadoc for `String`, and searching for the word "contain".

Answer (score 2):

You need a boolean condition in your `if`, [`String.indexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) returns an `int`. This

```
if(myArray[i].indexOf(Male){
```

should be something like

```
if (myArray[i].indexOf(Male) >= 0) {
```

**or** call [`String.contains(CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) like

```
if (myArray[i].contains(Male)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

There's String.contains(), which is designed for this. You use it like this

```
if(myArray[i].contains(Male){
    //found variable Male in array
}
```

If you want to use String.indexOf, then you need to check if the returned index is a positive integer, like this

```
if(myArray[i].indexOf(Male) >= 0){
    //found variable Male in array
}
```